# App Insights: Telemetry not showing Usage User data

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have my .Net Core app and I've added ITelemetryInitializer and got that all set up. In Application Insights for that app, under Performance => Operation Name => Samples => Suggested => Request Properties -> Show All => "Auth Id" and "Account Id" have values now, great.

Now, in Application Insights => Usage -> Users, I still only have 1 User. How do I get the Usage/Users functionality to read the User information that the requests under performance are collecting?

I've read several of MSFT documentation on [Send User Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-send-user-context) and [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-troubleshoot#counting-users), etc, but no luck. It seems like if I have "anonymous user ID, authenticated user ID, or session ID" in the Request Properties, the Usage telemetry should be picking it up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that talks about how to resolve the one user/session issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-troubleshoot#counting-users

Here is a code snippet that can be used for ASP.Net Core apps:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16002#issuecomment-503655010

Answer (score 0):

From [Counting users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/usage-troubleshoot#counting-users):

> If your app is sending authenticated user IDs, you can count based on authenticated user IDs in the users tool. **In the Show dropdown, choose Authenticated users.**

[image]